# Find elements within a set of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment I have something like

```
var inputs = $("form").find("input");
```

How can I do something like this?

```
var checkboxes = inputs.find("[type=checkbox]");
```

Thereby not having to traverse the entire form to find all checkboxes, because we know that all elements with `type=checkbox` will also be inputs -- which we've already collected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method:

```
var checkboxes = inputs.filter("[type=checkbox]");
```

The method also accepts a callback function:

```
var checkboxes = inputs.filter(function() {
   return this.type === 'checkbox';
});
```

Comment: This changes everything. :)